# Argocd Failed to Get Static Asset when Loading UI

Tags: amazon-eks, argocd

New to ArgoCD. I have deployed ArgoCD on my EKS cluster fronted with an AWS ALB Controller.

```
  ...
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-port: '[{"HTTPS":443}]'
  name: argo-ingress
  namespace: argocd
 spec:
  rules:
  - host: argocd.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: argocd-server
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

Given that the SSL is terminated at ALB, I deployed API server with the API server with the following parameters:

```
 spec:
  containers: 
  - command:
    - argocd-server
    - --insecure
    - --staticassets
    - /shared/app
```

When I port forward ArgoCD on the cluster, I am able to retrieve the objects locally.

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2080536 (2.0M) [application/javascript]
Saving to: ‘main.12b930b6a3d660c9da5a.js.2’

100%[===================================================================================================================>] 2,080,536   --.-K/s   in 0.03s

2020-10-26 02:14:53 (64.2 MB/s) - ‘main.12b930b6a3d660c9da5a.js.2’ saved [2080536/2080536]
```

However, when I use the browser to access the UI, I get 200 MSG and get a blank UI page and I get 400 error for the main.js and images.
Can anyone help me to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find the issue.
There was a typo in the ingress controller rules. As a result, all requests were being handled by the last ALB rule which resulted in 404. The fix was to include a '*' in the path. See below:

```
  ...
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-port: '[{"HTTPS":443}]'
  name: argo-ingress
  namespace: argocd
 spec:
  rules:
  - host: argocd.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: argocd-server
          servicePort: 80
        path: /*
```

Comment: Thank you. This gave me an idea. In my case, I had to use: `path: /` and `pathType: Prefix`.